# Can I run Raspbian OS and Octoprint os on same SD card?

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os-buster, raspberry-pi-imager

I am working with Raspberry pi 3b+. I have installed Raspbian OS on the SD card. Now, I have to install Octoprint on raspbian os system. How to do it?
While installing Octoprint from raspberry image viewer it requires SD card as storage system, so if I remove the SD card from raspberry pi and install ostoprint from image viewr using other PC, will it erase the raspbian OS and install a new Octoprint OS system or will it add the octoprint as an application.

I need to operate a 3D printer using octoprint on raspberry pi and also need raspbian OS system. Basically Octoprint should be installed as an application not as OS system on my raspberry pi.

Comment: This question is ambiguous. You CAN install multiple OS on a SD Card using PIN (although frankly it is easier and probably cheaper to use multiple SD Cards). You can install Octoprint on Raspberry Pi OS (which requires a level of Linux expertise). It is far from clear WHY you think you "also need raspbian OS system".

Comment: Incidentally Raspbian is meaningless. Raspberry Pi OS has been the official OS for several years.

Answer (score 1):

There are details of how to install Octoprint on a running Raspbian system at [the octoprint site](https://community.octoprint.org/t/setting-up-octoprint-on-a-raspberry-pi-running-raspberry-pi-os-debian/2337).

It warns the task is not for the faint hearted.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the best way to go would be using Docker.
https://github.com/OctoPrint/octoprint-docker

You could even run something like [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/), and then use a pre-existing [app template](https://docs.portainer.io/user/docker/templates) to deploy an Octoprint container.
[NovaspiritTech](https://www.youtube.com/@NovaspiritTech) has a good video on [Portainer setup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cO2-gQ09Jj0), which includes adding a repository of App Templates (including Octoprint)

Comment: Thank You for the response.